# May I use use 'System.IdentityHashCode()' in a JPA Entity constructor?

Tags: java, jpa, constructor, entity

is it allowed to store the object Id using System.IdentityHashCode() withing a JPA entity constructor ?

```
@Entity
...
public class Tool implements  ....
...
public Tool() {
        this.objId = System.identityHashCode(this);
    }
....
```

Formally the JPA entity constructor must be empty.

Thanks for any hint.

Gerry

Comment: I would suggest you provide for information to avoid your question being an XY problem. However, from my perspective, there is nothing against it. Hibernate just needs the no argument constructor to create an instance via reflection. If you intended to use the hash code as primary key, i would consider using a unique id generator instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I do not intend to use the objects hash as a entity Id, but for some other object reporting within Log Files. I want to know which entity reports. 
Sure that it also possible using the entityId, but in my case its easier.